# Fetching all Data from Multiple tables based on Single id

Tags: php, mysql

I have to select data from multiple tables based on single key value. I have one table called `maintable` where I will get all the ids from, and i have another 10 tables in the same database which have `maintable.id` as a foreign key. Now I have to retrieve data from the 10 tables where `maintable.id` matches in one single table.

The code I have tried is:

```
  $sql = select id from maintable;
  $runsql = mysql_query($sql);
  while($sqlRow = mysql_fetch_array($runsql ,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    for($i=1;$i<=10(This is another table count);$i++) {
      $servSql = "select * from table.$i where ref_id = ".$sqlRow['id'];
      $runServerSql = mysql_query($servSql);
      while($serverRow = mysql_fetch_array($runServSql,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Most definitely what you want is not a nested loop like this. Please refer to mysql join syntax

Comment: use [Joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm) my friend.

Comment: hi @e4c5 please can u suggest me with example because i am new to joins

Comment: You read the docs, make an attempt and if it does not succeed, post your table structure then someone will give you an example. that's how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in a join:

```
SELECT * FROM maintable m
INNER JOIN othertable o
ON m.id = o.id
```

That will select from both tables using an *inner join* ON the `id` column. You may want to look up a basic SQL tutorial to learn the basic types of joins you can use. Good luck!